# Remove the box character when doing a copy file + file

Tags: windows, windows-xp, copy, cmd

When doing the `copy file + file` command in windows XP CMD, the file with the appended information will have a box character at the end of the last line. And subsequent `copy file + file` commands will leave additional box characters as well.

Is there a way to keep this from occurring? Or removing it afterwards?

Comment: What is the end-of-line encoding used in the files? Is it Unix (`\n`), Mac (`\r`) or Windows (`\r\n`)?

Comment: I know what you're asking, but how do I find that answer?

Comment: (assuming the file is a text file), when you open it in Notepad, does it display correctly, or is it all smushed onto one line? (This isn't an _exact_ way, but a quick-and-dirty way to do a basic check)

Comment: it displays correctly in notepad, with the exception of the box character at the end of the last line that was appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hex viewer to see what that added byte might be.  I'd guess at 0x1a, a Ctrl+Z used to indicate the end of text files.  This goes all the way back to CP/M, an early operating system that didn't have a file size property so needed a special character to indicate EOF on text files.

Use the /B option to tell COPY that the files are binary.

Comment: You're completely right. And using the /B switch does take away the hex character. Thanks for the answer.